# Multilevel transclusion in Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

I have a generic `<item>` directive, and a `<listing>` directive with filters and pagination tools for listing that `<item>`:

[image]

**Example**: https://plnkr.co/edit/r6byzhFX5m674ONhH1JS?p=preview

The `<listing>` template is something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <item date="item">
        <ng-transclude ng-transclude-slot="itemContent"></ng-transclude>
  </item>
</div>
```

The `<item>` directive uses the new Angular 1.5 multi-slot transclusion to customize footer and header easily:

```
<item data="itemData">
  <header>My header</header>
  <footer>My custom footer</footer>
</item>
```

My problem arises when I try to customize that items when using `<listing>`. If I use something like this:

```
<listing items="myItems">
  <item-content>
        <header>{{ item.name }}</header>
        <footer>My custom footer for {{ item.name }}</footer>
  </item-content>
</listing>
```

It doesn't work, because the `<item-content>` gets inserted into `<item>`, but `<header>` and `<footer>` don't get transcluded into their proper places, and they cannot read the `item` scope variable. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you create a plnker or fiddle for this? Would like to look into this issue a bit more.

Comment: Here it is: https://plnkr.co/edit/r6byzhFX5m674ONhH1JS?p=preview

Comment: As far as I can see what you are trying to do wont work. By design, transclude changes the way scopes are nested. It makes it so that the contents of a transcluded directive have whatever scope is outside the directive, rather than whatever scope is on the inside. It gives the contents access to the outside scope. So in your example the transcluded content inside `<item-header>` and `<item-footer>` accesses the controller scope. There might be a way to get around this using the `transcludeFn` parameter of `link`. But I'm unsure how `transcludeFn` works with the multi-slot feature.

Comment: I think I've found a solution. Will post back later today.

Comment: I will wait your post

Comment: Can you explain your solution, @Beyers?

Comment: I'm sorry to report back that I haven't been able to find a solution for you. The closest I got is this: https://plnkr.co/edit/cmedSodmWtTe22bni9oS?p=preview Using the transclude function of link I can actually the correct data binding, but it doesn't work with actual transclusion.

Comment: I see... Anyway, thank you for your attempt!

Answer (score 2):

First, in the listing template you should change `ng-transclude-slot="itemHeader"` by `ng-transclude="itemHeader"` and `ng-transclude-slot="itemFooter"` by `ng-transclude="itemFooter"` to get the transclusion to work.

Then, you have in single and list example a mistake. If you change in the provided plunkr `{items[0].name}` by the expected `{data.name}` in the single example you will see that the name is not being displayed anymore. The second thing to do is to fix this shared problem.

Comment: That's true, I was using `ng-transclude-slot` when `ng-transclude` should have been used. I've updated the plunker.
Any idea about how to solve the shared problem?

Comment: please see if following questions can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794968/angular-directive-transclusion-and-inheritance and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR; Working example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/1ideOiohle8AEzkDJ333?p=preview

The basic problem you're running into is that when you transclude, the scope you have access to is the top level scope.  What you want is to reference the item level scope from outside the directive.

So, instead of using transclusion on the listing directive, I bind a string template as an attribute.  I have to use a compile function to pick up the raw string value before angular pulls out the `{{}}` placeholders and then I use `$interpolate` to create template functions `itemHeaderTemplate` and `itemFooterTemplate` which are then used in the template like so `ng-bind-html="itemHeaderTemplate({item: item})"`.

Note: In order to use `ng-bind-html` you need to include the `ngSanitize` module or you'll get a security exception.